# Error "Method Post of object IOWSPostData failed" when import Excel as new list

Tags: error, excel, import

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise standard edition. Our users desktop have Office 2010 installed.

Recently user test the import Excel spreadsheet into SharePoint 2013 list function. He tested with a very simple Excel sheet. However when he selected some cells and click "Import" button, error "Method Post of object IOWSPostData failed" is prompted.

1. I found the same error on Internet but all of them are about older version SharePoint.
2. We tested create a subsite and then import the same Excel again. No error is occur.

Why is that?

Comment: "create root site collection" is not applicable with SharePoint 365, which is where I'm seeing this problem.

Comment: Then how do u solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to be an old bug (or old design) of SharePoint.

The site collection with import problem have URL `http://sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/`. It happened that every site collections under same web application cannot import Excel. Also every subsite (e.g. `http://sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/subsite/`) can import Excel without problem.

My gut feeling told me to check our web application root (`http://sharepoint.com/`) and found the site collection was deleted during my previous test. It is just a dummy site contain nothing so I do not pay much attention before. After I recreate the site collection with a normal team site template, everything is back to work as before.

I believe the root cause is the "Import Excel" function make use of some Macro to import from Excel. However it assume you have root site collection created.

Comment: Did you find out what was the root cause?  I have not deleted anything and i still getting the same error.

Comment: The official solution is to create root site collection. Without root site collection the macro bug will occur.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after creating root site collection.